# Disabling multi-touch feature in Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, touchscreen, feature-regression

While I'm developing a POS application, I do have some **issues with windows 10** multi finger touch. I need to **disable multi finger** touch and all other **touch gestures** and make the touch panel **behave like a mouse**.

[image]

What if I go back and use **windows 7**? (I dont want to) could it be better?

Comment: Uninstall the drivers for the touchpad, this will disable the gestures, if there isn't an option in the properties of the device itself.

Comment: Uninstalling the driver disabled the hole touch feature not only the gestures. +1 for the comment but sorry it doesn't help.